# UIImage in EAGLView, not converting to texture

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es

I want to ask if it is possible to render an UIImage in 3D space in EAGLView without converting it to a texture and generating the texture first.

As you can guess, that is what I am doing now, but this gives me some problems. The texture can't be larger than 2048x2048 (depends on hardware as I know?), which means I will need to create my own subview tiling, if I am to show more pictures(textures).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit odd question.. The answer is yes but I wouldn't go there. You could for instance create a point cloud drawing each pixel as a point in openGL. This would result in unlimited texture data size but would be very heavy on a vertex shader. All you need to do is bind a color array pointer from the image and create the vertex array for positions for each pixel of the image (it might even be possible to push those data to GPU via buffers).

Again, I wouldn't go there and I never tried this. A few problems that might or might not occur from the top of my head are data overflowing (too many points to draw), performance issue, magnification (could result in empty pixels), minification (could result in pixels overlapping).

Overall I would say tiling is the way to go.